# Apache Camel throw alert when no files pulled from FTP after X time

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I've written a camel route that pulls files from a FTP server and does some message transformations onto them. An example scenario is that I'm polling the FTP server every 1 hour. If no files have been pulled for the last 12 hours however, I want to send an alert notification.

I've read through [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065483/send-an-email-notification-if-no-files-pulled-from-ftp) and added the sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true option so I can tell when no new messages have been polled. However I only want to send an alert if no messages have been polled after X time. I've been thinking of using a timer that sends a alert every X time however if a new message is polled then that timer's countdown is refreshed. Does anyone know how to implement such a timer? Is there an easier way alerting that I'm not thinking of?

Unrelated question, what's the syntax to use when a FTP login username contains the "@" symbol? Something like this: from("ftp:user@server@ftpserver.com/password=password")

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Have a look at camel's Quartz support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the timer might be to record the first time you receive a empty message. Store the date and time then keep on polling. Every time you hit another empty message check if the date and time difference is bigger than the threshold then fire a alert.

If you received a empty message and then you poll something reset the state. Its a very simple finite state machine you need to code. Might be less clumsy than a timer.

Just a idea.

Comment: I hadn't thought it that, it seems more elegant than resetting a timer each time. Thanks!